While intitializing ckeditor with '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor' it's giving ckeditor-duplicated-modules error
I am trying to add placeholder plugin, I have tried with @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic, it's giving error ckeditor-duplicated-modules. Then i read it's documentation it's say to use '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor', I have tried this too still getting same error
My import code is below


import { CModal } from '@coreui/react';
import { immediateToast } from "izitoast-react";
import Breadcrumbs from "../../CommonElements/Breadcrumbs";
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
//import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
//import { Command, Plugin } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor'
//import Placeholder from "ckeditor5-placeholder";
//import { ClassicEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic';


return(
                        <CKEditor
                            editor={ClassicEditor}
                            data={initValues.report}
                            config={{ placeholder: "Add Report..." }}
                            onReady={(editor) => {
                                //console.log("CKEditor5 React Component is ready to use!", editor);
                            }}
                            onChange={(event, editor) => {
                                const data = editor.getData();
                                //console.log({ event, editor, data });
                                setMainValue(data, "MainScope")
                            }}
                        />                    
)



I have tried every method which mention in ckeditor documentation, I need to add some dynamically created placeholder
